# Splitting a string to create a HTML link

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with an API that returns strings with inline links like so:

```
This is a question I'm asking on <my_link type="externalLink" data="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</my_link> about splitting a string and reconstructing as a HTML link.
```

The reason for this is apparently so the API can be used by both web and native platforms and that HTML is kept away from the data. There are also `internalLink` types which will allow app developers to link to content within an app rather than opening a web browser.

I need to be able to pass this string into a function and return the full string with an  tag like so:

```
This is a question I'm asking on <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">StackOverflow</a> about splitting a string and reconstructing as a HTML link.
```

Another thing to consider is that the string could have multiple links in it.

My initial attempt is basic and does get `externalLink` from the first link but I'm unsure of how to get the value of the `data` attribute and then re-run for any other links.

```
export default function convertLink(string) {
  let stringWithLinks = string;

  if (string.includes('<my_link')) {
    const typeStart = string.indexOf('"') + 1;
    const typeEnd = string.indexOf('"', typeStart);
    const typeText = string.substring(typeStart, typeEnd); // externalLink
  }

  return stringWithLinks;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the string as HTML of a new element. Loop over all the `my_link` elements extracting the relevant data, then build a new anchor that can then replace the `my_link` on each iteration.

```
function convertAllLinks(str) {
  let el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = str;
  el.querySelectorAll('my_link').forEach(link => {
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = link.getAttribute('data');
    anchor.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    anchor.textContent = link.textContent;
    link.parentNode.replaceChild(anchor, link);
  });
  return el.innerHTML;
}

convertAllLinks(str);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w1r0u261/1/)**

Comment: The only thing missing was `anchor.textContent = link.textContent;` to add the link text in between the tags. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @GuerillaRadio, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer/demo to reflect that change.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the string as `.innerHTML` of a dynamically created element and use `.getAttribute()` to get the `data` attribute of `<my_link>` element, set `.innerHTML` of dynamically created `<a>` element and use  `.replaceChild()` to replace `<my_link>` with `<a>` element

```js
let str = `This is a question I'm asking on <my_link type="externalLink" data="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</my_link> about splitting a string and reconstructing as a HTML link.`;

let div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML = str;

let my_links = Array.prototype.map.call(div.querySelectorAll("my_link"), link =>
                 link.getAttribute("data"));

console.log(my_links);

for (let link of my_links) {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = link;
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.innerHTML = div.querySelector("my_link").innerHTML;
  div.replaceChild(a, div.querySelector("my_link"))
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `DOMParser()`, in case you might need to do any more DOM modifications later on.

```js
let stringWithLinks = `This is a question I'm asking on <my_link type="externalLink" data="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</my_link> about splitting a string and reconstructing as a HTML link.`,
    tempDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<doc>' + stringWithLinks + '</doc>', "text/xml"),
    linkElements = tempDOM.getElementsByTagName('my_link');

for (let i=0; i<linkElements.length; i++) {
  let newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.setAttribute('src', linkElements[i].getAttribute('data'));
  
  let linkType = linkElements[i].getAttribute('type');
  if (linkType == 'externalLink') {
    newA.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
  newA.innerHTML = linkElements[i].innerHTML;
  
  tempDOM.documentElement.replaceChild(newA, linkElements[i]);
}

console.log(tempDOM.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: However, I guess there's not really an advantage for using this approach over a temporary dom element - just a preference.